# Retain Value of Select Tag after Submit - PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to add subject to a teacher's workload. I have a validation before inserting the user input to my workload table, mostly for detecting schedule conflict.

Now, what I want is to retain the selected value of the user and display it again after the validation fails. So that the user doesn't have to select the subject name, class name, and class adviser again.

I've attached my code for the class adviser selection.

```html
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "smis");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM teacherData";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
echo "<select  id='modalINPUT' name='teacherID' required>";
echo"<option  value=''>Select Adviser</option>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
 echo "<option value='".$row['teacherID']."'>".$row['Fname'] ." ". $row['Mname'] ." " .$row['Lname'] . "</option>";
}
 echo "</select>";
?>

/*
Once validation fails, is there a way where I can display the selected value? 
Like display the name of the teacher.
*/
```

Comment: Store entered values in SESSION.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could compare the posted value against the id of the current row. And add `selected` attribute if the values are the same.

```
// create $selected variable to get "selected" or "":
$selected = isset($_POST['teacherID']) && $_POST['teacherID'] == $row['teacherID'] 
          ? 'selected' : '' ;

// add $selected to the <option> tag:
echo "<option value='".$row['teacherID']."' $selected>"
    . $row['Fname'] ." ". $row['Mname'] ." " .$row['Lname'] 
    . "</option>";
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. your solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use:

```
$teacherID = !empty($_POST['teacherID']) ? $_POST['teacherID'] : '';
```

right before your sql query

Then to display selected value on select box, you can check if posted id matches with current id and print out selected parameter for the according option field:

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['teacherID'].'"'.($teacherID == $row['teacherID'] ? ' selected="selected"' : '').'>'.htmlspecialchars($row['Fname']) .' '. htmlspecialchars($row['Mname']) .' ' .htmlspecialchars($row['Lname']) . '</option>';
```

EDIT: Take a look on my edited answer - use single quotes for better performance (so PHP doesnt have to scan your double quoted string for vars), and ALWAYS process your information, which you get from DB with htmlspecialchars, so you don't mess up your html, when something improper is saved into DB

EDIT: Also do not select all data from MYSQL table, unless you need to. To gain performance, select only fields you need in your query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT teacherID, Fname, Mname, Lname FROM teacherData';
```